# service worker fail NTLM auth with 504 error

Tags: service-worker, chromium, angular-service-worker

Try to use Service worker in my Angular7 app. ServiceWorker compiled by ServiceWorkerModule.

This issue was reproduced only if I use a service worker.

[image: POST req without pre-flight OPTIONS req init by SW]

[image: fetched req by service-worker]

I can not understand why SW initiate auth POST request without sending pre-flight OPTIONS req.
May be anybody can help with this issue?

requests without WS:

[image: OPTIONS req]

[image: POST req]